# Is is possible to set value in property without a setter?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-2.0, mailchimp, mandrill

I am implementing mandrill in .net application using this package (https://github.com/shawnmclean/Mandrill-dotnet) Now there is a model "EmailMessage" that is used to send an email. Inside of EmailMessage model there is a property "GlobalMergeVars":

```
   [JsonProperty("global_merge_vars")]
   public List<MergeVar> GlobalMergeVars { get; }
```

Now we can see that there is no setter for GlobalMergeVars but I have to set a value for this. If we go to this link (https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.html) and click on "Try it" button then we can set value for GlobalMergeVars but I think there is some problem in the package I am using. But I can't switch to other package because it is very flexible as compare to others. So is there anyway to set value for GlobalMergeVars?

PS: I have also opened an issue on github repo. But due to some close deadlines I need a quick fix.

Comment: Have you tried from the constructor of the class?

Comment: There is only an empty constructor in EmailMessage class

Comment: Add more detail code please! Also tell on which case you want to set value.

Comment: The answer is: read at https://github.com/shawnmclean/Mandrill-dotnet/blob/master/src/Mandrill/Models/EmailMessage.cs starting from line 376. That method is designed for your case

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I've found the class you're talking about [here](https://github.com/shawnmclean/Mandrill-dotnet/blob/master/src/Mandrill/Models/EmailMessage.cs). Although that property of `EmailMessage` is given differently than you show in the question:

```
public class EmailMessage
{
    #region Public Properties
    ...
    /// <summary>
    ///   Gets the global_merge_vars.
    /// </summary>
    public List<MergeVar> GlobalMergeVars { get; private set; }
```

*(The differences between the code here and the code given in the question are immaterial - I'm just wondering whether I'm looking at the right file!)*

The missing `set` is the equivalent of `private set`. Within that class is the following method, which will allow you to set the variables:

```
public void AddGlobalVariable(string name, dynamic content)
{
  if (GlobalMergeVars == null)
  {
    GlobalMergeVars = new List<MergeVar>();
  }

  var mv = new MergeVar {Name = name, Content = content};
  GlobalMergeVars.Add(mv);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you already got an answer for your particular case, but since the question was "*Is is possible to set value in property without a setter?*" and it was so decidedly said that you cannot directly set the value from outside the class, I just want to provide an example of just doing that...

If you are willing to use reflection you can actually set the value from outside the class.

You just need to be a bit tricky.

You need to abuse the fact that private fields made for Auto properties are made by compiler desugaring and not by the JITer.

This means that there will actually be a private field named like this in the assembly: <[NameOfProperty]>k__BackingField.

The Compiler desugaring adds < and > because they are illegal to add as a private field name by developer code.

Here is an example where I am trying to find the private backing field of a property named GlobalIgnores which does not have a setter (meaning the same as having a private setter).

```
public class Configuration
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        GlobalIgnores = new List<string>{"IgnoredPropertyName"};
    }
    
    public IEnumerable<string> GlobalIgnores { get; }
}

protected IList<string> PropertyNamesToTempIgnore { get; } = new List<string>{"ReplacedIgnoredPropertyName"};

public void SetPrivateBackingFieldOfPropertyWithNoSetter()
{
    var configuration = new Configuration();
    var configurationType = configuration.GetType();
    const string globalIgnoresFieldName = "<GlobalIgnores>k__BackingField";
    var fieldInfo = configurationType.GetField(globalIgnoresFieldName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
    fieldInfo.SetValue(configuration, PropertyNamesToTempIgnore);
}
```

Disclaimer: I wouldn't recommend using this unless you absolutely have to, as the naming of these autogenerated private fields are not 100% specified in the C# specification and it could change in different compiler implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but if there's no public setter you cannot directly set the value from outside the class. Other options would be through a constructor or a method that allows such. But it does not seem as if you have any such options available.

On a side note, just check if that property does not perhaps have a parent property that you can set as a whole. For example in C# when working with Fonts, to set the Font of a label for instance. Some of the Font object's properties are "read-only" and cannot be set externally. But the Font object itself can be set. So in such cases you have to create a new Font object locally and set the needed props and then assign/set that as the new Font.

Hope you find a work-around in time.

**UPDATE:**

Sir Rufo just gave you the solution:

> The answer is: read at
>   github.com/shawnmclean/Mandrill-dotnet/blob/master/src/Mandrill/…
>   starting from line 376. That method is designed for your case

Comment: You forgot to mention that there might be a method that could do the job (in fact, there is one) ;o)

Comment: @SirRufo - No, I did mention that and just added you solution. Kudos!